# Glade 3.18 + GTK3 - Make children keep internal size

Tags: user-interface, gtk3, glade

So i have a GUI with a toplevel `GtkWindow` that has alot of boxes and windows beneath it. See image below

[image: tree]

the problem is when a user resizes `window1` (downwards) , the bottom element, i.e `statusbar2` only enlarges and fills up the rest of the available area.
The notion of a status bar is that it should be always the same size, like 80 px of height. What I want to do is that when a user resizes the window, the internal components stay the same *relative* height and width. Atleast the status bar. So when i drag down to enlarge, the `box3` item should only enlarge. The `statusbar2` should "hook" onto the bottom edge of the window and stay the same size.

This must be doable surely? 
If you need the glade file, I might be able to upload it
Any help is appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the status bar's `vexpand` property to False, and set the `vexpand` property to True of whatever widget(s) you *would* like to absorb the extra space.